# how to filter in Mongo cosmosDB with condition contains 2 fields or more

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I would like to filter a list user that has both status is "Active" + "Renew"
I already try like this `{user: {$elemMatch: {status: {$in: ["active", "renew"] }}}}`
But the result is just show the user with active, or new... not both of them.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the values in the `status` array to match all the elements in the input array, you need the `$all` operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  "user": {
    $elemMatch: {
      status: {
        $all: [
          "active",
          "renew"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gCo-ygA5t9u)